# ImageMagick on iOS: Blurring and blending an image with itself

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I'm trying to take an image, blur it with a 10px radius (both `-blur` and `-gaussian-blur` should work fine), then give it a 50% opacity, and finally overlay the blurred transparent image with the original. Here's what I've got so far:

```
convert sample.png \( sample.png -gaussian-blur 10 -matte -channel A 
-evaluate set 50% \) -composite dreamy.png
```

Here's the original image:

[image: Original image]

And here is what it should look like after the effect is applied:

[image: Image with filter]

However, what I get with the command above just looks very similar to the original. Anyone have any ideas how to achieve the effect I want? If I do what I originally described in an image manipulation program, I get the desired effect, so something is probably wrong with the command I'm using.

Edit:

`-adaptive-blur` seems to get me closer to the desired effect, but still I'd like to use `-blur`.

Edit 2:

`convert round-face-winslet.jpg \( +clone -blur 0x10 \) -compose Screen -composite round-face-winslet_soft.jpg`

...gets me yet closer to the result, but no matter what kind of `-compose` method I choose, the result *still* does not look like the desired image. It's either too light or too dark. What should be a simple 50% opacity blended with the underlying original picture, for some reason doesn't want to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the effect you are looking for can be found in the [ImageMagick compose examples](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/) in the "Softened Blurring" section.

```
  convert face.png  -morphology Convolve Gaussian:0x3  face_strong_blur.png
  convert face.png  face_strong_blur.png \
          -compose Blend -define compose:args=60,40% -composite \
          face_soft_blur.png
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Great example. I tried this before though, but could not get the -morphology option to work. Perhaps the version is outdated...?

Comment: convert --version yields:

Version: ImageMagick 6.7.3-1 2011-12-01 Q16 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC

this was installed via MacPorts as of an upgrade to Lion I did yesterday.  So, it's probably pretty new.

Comment: I get: convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 6.2.8 10/06/10 Q16 file:/usr/share/ImageMagick-6.2.8/doc/index.html
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2006 ImageMagick Studio LLC. However, from the website I get: The "-morphology" operator (basic methods) and the initial set of kernels was added to ImageMagick version 6.5.9-0 by myself, while I was on a vacation in China. December 2009 to January 2010.
However it is posible to perform simplified 'square' kernel morphology using the older and closely related "-convolve" method. See Alternative Basic Morphology Techniques below.

Comment: Could you btw tell me how to create your above command using _-gaussian-blur_ instead of _-morphology_, plus write it as a single command? That would be extremely helpful and I'd be happy to mark your answer as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

An older tutorial on this technique ([here](http://luminous-landscape.com/tutorials/gaussian.shtml)) suggests lightening the blurred layer and blending in Multiply mode.  I expect that darkening the blurred layer and blending with Screen would also work.  Don't use a standard 50/50 blend - it doesn't have the same glowing appearance.

In your sample, the shadows of the processed image are lighter.  Multiplying can only make an image darker, so I'm guessing they took the darken-Screen approach.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I created the images of Kate Winslet just as described in the question, using Paint.Net. The top layer was blurred with a 10px radius, and the entire layer given 50% opacity. The layer mode was "normal", but this is AFAIK not an option in IM. Then the layer was merged with the layer underneath. My problem is that no matter what I try, the pixels are not blended in the same way in Paint.Net and IM. Any suggestions?

Comment: The ImageMagick equivalent of "normal" is `blend`.  Documentation: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/compose/#blend

Comment: Thanks, then this mode works different than the "normal" blending mode in Paint.Net since the images tend to be brighter or darker no matter what option I use...